# XSLT: pass attribute from xml element to another xml element how param

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message field1="11" field2="22">
    <sub1 sub_field1="sub11" sub_field2="sub22" sub2_id="12243"/>
    <sub1 sub_field1="sub11" sub_field2="sub12" sub2_id="12244"/>      
    <sub2 sub2_field="sub21" sub2_field2="sub22" id="12243"/>
    <sub2 sub2_field="sub23" sub2_field2="sub24" id="12243"/>
    <sub2 sub2_field="sub25" sub2_field2="sub26" id="12244"/>
    <sub2 sub2_field="sub27" sub2_field2="sub28" id="12244"/>
</message>
```

Here the structure, what I need:

```
<message>
    <sub1>
      <sub_field1>value</sub_field1>
      <sub_field2>value</sub_field2>
      <sub2_list>
        <sub2>
          <sub2_field>value</sub2_field>
          <sub2_field2>value</sub2_field2>
        </sub2>
        <sub2>
          <sub2_field>value</sub2_field>
          <sub2_field2>value</sub2_field2>
        </sub2>
      </sub2_list>
    </sub1>
    <sub1>
      <sub_field1>value</sub_field1>
      <sub_field2>value</sub_field2>
      <sub2_list>
        <sub2>
          <sub2_field>value</sub2_field>
          <sub2_field2>value</sub2_field2>
        </sub2>
        <sub2>
          <sub2_field>value</sub2_field>
          <sub2_field2>value</sub2_field2>
        </sub2>
      </sub2_list>
    </sub1>
</message>
```

And I'm dont understand, how to pass sub2_id from sub1 tag, to id sub2 tag, how to use sub2_id how param?...........................................

My xsl looks like this:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="message">
                <xsl:variable name="sub2_id=" select="@sub2_id"/>
                <xsl:element name="sub1">
                    <xsl:element name="sub_field1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@sub_field1"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="sub_field2>">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@sub_field2>"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="sub2_list">
                            <xsl:for-each select="sub2[@id=$sub2_id]">
                                <xsl:element name="zpu">
                                    <xsl:element name="sub2_field">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@sub2_field="/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                    <xsl:element name="sub2_field2">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@sub2_field2"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have some syntax errors in your code, for example `sub2_id=` is not a valid variable name

```
<xsl:variable name="sub2_id=" select="@sub2_id"/>
```

Possibly you meant to do this...

```
<xsl:variable name="sub2_id" select="@sub2_id"/>
```

Maybe you have missed out some code, but when you define that variable, you are positioned on a `message` element, when really you should be on a `sub1` element, so you would expect to have an `xsl:for-each`, or `xsl:apply-templates` in your code to select `sub1`.

Assuming you were positioned on a `sub1` element, then in that case the `sub2` is a sibling of `sub1`, so to select it you would do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="../sub2[@id=$sub2_id]">
```

However, it might be beneficial to use a `xsl:key` here to look up the `sub2` elements.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="sub2" match="sub2" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="message">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="sub1" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sub1">
    <sub1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@sub_field1|@sub_field2"/>
        <sub2list>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('sub2', @sub2_id)">
                <sub2>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@sub2_field|@sub2_field2"/>
                </sub2>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </sub2list>
    </sub1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I have an added a generic template for converting attributes to elements, which greatly simplifies the code.

Comment: Thank you, <xsl:for-each select="../sub2[@id=$sub2_id]"> this is helpfull, your better template I will use later.